# How to Make a Random Sprite Position Generator in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, random, generator

I have created a game where birds will appear randomly on the screen.
Portrait mode.
Want them to appear from a random x position (from the middle of the frame)
I also want them to position at a random Y position of the screen (max top of "self" screen)

The top line of code works(randomGenerator), but only goes on one side of the screen (X Position).
I cannot put a negative value into the X position because it will not allow.

I then was trying other things as you can see.

what am I doing wrong?

```
var randomGenerater = CGPoint(x:Int(arc4random()%180) ,y:Int(arc4random()%260))
var minXPosition = (CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) * CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(300)))
var RandomYPosition = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)))
var trial = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) - Float(UINT32_MAX))) 
var randomGenerator2 = CGPointMake(minXPosition, trial)
 bird.position = randomGenerator2
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally,

```
func randomInRange(lo: Int, hi : Int) -> Int {
    return lo + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(hi - lo + 1)))
}
```

gives a random integer in the range `lo ... hi`, so

```
// x coordinate between MinX (left) and MaxX (right):
let randomX = randomInRange(Int(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)), Int(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)))
// y coordinate between MinY (top) and MidY (middle):
let randomY = randomInRange(Int(CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)), Int(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)))
let randomPoint = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
```

should give the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on this randomInRange.
The issue with what you have giving me comes up with errors as the hi and lo have not been set.

I don't quite understand the algorithm to be quite fair, so I cannot go through it.
But thank you for your help any :)

Comment: @RickC: Sorry, I do not understand. You have to *define* the `randomInRange()` function somewhere in your source file. Then `let randomX = randomInRange(..., ...)` *calls* the function with the given values.